# generate uuid for insert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to generate uuid like this `e58ed763-928c-4155-bee9-fdbaaadc15f3` when data is inserted into table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bin_lists
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    bin integer,
    card_brand character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT bin_lists_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I tried to use this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO bin_lists(id, bin, card_brand, status) VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), 122088, 'UATP', 'ACTIVE');
```

I get error: `ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist`
Do you know how I can solve this?

Is it better to use this column definition `id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid (),` and let database to generate uuid number for each insert?

Comment: `gen_random_uuid()` is fine. No need to install an extension

Answer (score 1):

I can't say which uuid function you should use, but if you want to use the uuid_generate_v4() function, I believe it exists in the uuid-ossp extension. If the extension is available in your server, run:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

Answer (score 0):

To get `uuid_generate_v4()`, you would have to create the `"uuid-ossp"` extension. But if all you need is a version 4 UUID, and you are using a sufficiently recent version of PostgreSQL, you might as well use the built-in function `gen_random_uuid()` that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Can you show me what is the proper way to write the SQL insert statement? I get `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist`

Comment: The cause lies in something you failed to reveal: you must be using an old version of PostgreSQL. Go with the other answer then.